# Volume of revolution ,least posible volume

Tags: calculus

Of all parabola passing through points $[0,0]$ and $[2,2]$ ,determine the one which , when revolved about the x-axis , generate a solid of revolution with least possible volume between $x=0$ and $x=2$. Notice that : such a parabla may be taken of the form $u(x) =x+kx(2-x)$ where $k$ is to be determined

I started with $v= \int (\pi(f(x)^2 )$ from $x=a$ to $x= b$

Comment: You could learn MathJax to input formula at here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: I think your approach is correct. What did you get then?

Comment: I dont now , i stoped.

Comment: Any one know how it solve please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: notice that your $f(x)$ is $x+kx(x-2)$, with $k$ a constant. $a=0,b=2$ are the integration limits.

Integrate it, you will get a equation with respect to $k$.

To minimize it, find the derivative with respect to $k$, and set it to zero.

Comment: WHAT ABOUT points [0,0] and [2,2] ??

Comment: The x-values are the integration limits. The y values can be obtained from plugging x-values into $f(x)$, which verifies that $f(x)$ is the correct function to use.